# Android: when use startActivity(intent) the code execute other

Tags: android, android-intent

I may have a trivial problem but I can not solve.
If I run this piece of code:

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+name);
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
boolean esiste = isPackageExists(name);
Log.i("Esiste", "Esiste il packeges? : "+esiste);
if (!esiste) { //code }
```

everything is fine, but when execute starActivity(), the code starts the application but also performs check...
I would like to execute check when return to the myapplication ... help me

Comment: use startActivityForResult(), then onActivityResult() call, when you returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since every App runs in its own Thread, your App continues after calling the delete action.
You can do the checking after the called acitivty is closed, like this: 
Change `startActivity(uninstallIntent);` to `startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent, 1);`

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1){
            boolean esiste = isPackageExists(name);
            Log.i("Esiste", "Esiste il packeges? : "+esiste);
            if (!esiste) { //code }
        }
    }
```

If you call an Intent via `startActivityForResult` the Method `onActivityResult` will be called after returning from the called Activity. The variable `requestCode` is used to identify the requests.